# how atheticate in zf2 restful

Tags: rest, service, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm working on a project with ZF2 restful and Doctrine 2, and my problem is I have no idea how to do atenticación to identify the user with username and password, to consume services. I wish someone would help me and guide this.
thank you.

*[EDIT 1]*

I've been reading about authentication headers html, but really want someone to guide me with this, I have not understood.

[zf2authenticaterestful](https://juriansluiman.nl/article/147/api-header-based-authentication-in-zend-framework-2) 
This was the best I found for ZF2, but I think you are using a third party module, and I lose a little when you do this:

`$publicKey = $this->extractPublicKey($authorization);
 $user  = $this->getUserRepository()->findByPublicKey($publicKey);`

I do not understand where they come from these methods, or if you should have a table in the database with the public key, and where I get this key.

Comment: Hello, what did you try so far?

Comment: add more information to my question.